# Eclipse issues with 'exec'

Tags: java, eclipse, exec

I am trying to execute a java code that makes an exec call to a python script.
Below is my code:

Example.java

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try{
             process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python /home/user/Desktop/example.py");
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    }
}
```

Python file: example.py

```
fp = open('sample.txt','w')
fp.write("Test Output written to file")
```

When I run the java code from the terminal I get the expected results.(I'm using **CentOS 7**)
exec call is made from java to the python script, python script then writes the string to the file

However the same code does not work in eclipse.
***Note: The python script and sample.txt are located at /home/user/Desktop/**
The exec call doesn't get executed.

Can someone help me with this? Is there any additional setting in eclipse that needs to be done? I am using **Eclipse Java EE**

Comment: Are you sure `exec` is not executed? In Eclipse by default, the working directory is your project directory and you have to refresh (F5) to see the created `sample.txt` file.

Comment: @howlger I've mentioned the absolute path to my python script. This python script will search for a file sample.txt in its current directory and write to it. Should I move these scripts within eclipse and change the path?

Comment: You do not need to move `example.py`. Your code is equivalent to call `python /home/user/Desktop/example.py` on the command line in your directory of your Eclipse project. `sample.txt` is a relative path so it will be created in the current directory.